# EF 5 Code First Extra Foreign Keys being Generated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Occasionally EF would include a *_Id foreign key to the generated tables, even though I specify the foreign key.

Classes:

```
public partial class Product : IFoo, IBar
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore, ScriptIgnore, ForeignKey("InsuranceClassId"), Display(Name = "Insurance Class")]
    public virtual InsuranceClass InsuranceClass { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Insurance Class")]
    public int InsuranceClassId { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore, ScriptIgnore, ForeignKey("ProductGroupId"), Display(Name = "Product Group")]
    public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Group")]
    public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }

    //[Snip]
}

public partial class InsuranceClass : IFoo, IBar
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255), Display(Name = "Description"), Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore, ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public InsuranceClass()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    //[Snip]
}
```

But my Products table end up like this:

```
Products
Id
InsuranceClassId
ProductGroupId
InsuranceClass_Id
ProductGroup_Id
```

What am I doing wrong? It only happens on a few tables.

Comment: In the migration file EF creates FKs to both properties to both tables, .ForeignKey("dbo.InsuranceClasses", t => t.InsuranceClassId)
.ForeignKey("dbo.ProductGroups", t => t.ProductGroupId)
.ForeignKey("dbo.ProductGroups", t => t.ProductGroup_Id)
.ForeignKey("dbo.InsuranceClasses", t => t.InsuranceClass_Id)

Answer (score 0):

Not real answer, but last time this happens to me, i have wrong mapping, like `HasOptional(xx).WithMany();` (missing `.HasForeignKey(xx)`) and EF Conventions kick in another `xx_Id` column - maybe you should check this.

Comment: I have no code in OnModelCreating except for modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();